# Separate TV/movie tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a recent question about the movie *Mission: Impossible*.  I elected not to tag it [`mission-impossible`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mission-impossible), as the description for the tag reads

> Series of spy movies based on the early 70s television show of the same name detailing the actions of cadre of secret agents combating terrorism or high crime on a global scale.

An edit adding the tag was proposed and approved.

When I look at the tag, most of the questions seem to be about a *Mission: Impossible* movie or about both the movie and the TV show.

Should there exist separate tags for movies/movie series which share a name with a TV show?  If not, I'd suggest that such tags' descriptions be updated to clarify that they cover both movies and TV.

Comment: This is currently under discussion here: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/rules-for-multiple-media-using-the-same-name We're being a bit slow on making a decision.

Comment: There should indeed be separate tags and the accepted policy is to add a `-tv` appendage where appropriate (http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1070/49). But I didn't even know there were questions about the TV-show. Thanks for noticing...Uh, wait. There doesn't really seem to be a single question about the series only. There is only *one* about the movies *and* the series, so I guess there just was no need seen in adding an additional series tag to that question.

Comment: But still, I have to wonder why the tag description repelled you from using it when that clearly says it's used for the movie.

Comment: That one was my bad -- reading the description quickly, I read that it was about the "70s television show."